# ArrayList - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, collections

the problem is that there are more than a million entries in my list, after which it falls.
I need the whole list to pass it to jasper to generate a report. Can someone tell me how to deal with this? Maybe there are some utilities for this (compact in terms of memory collections)

```
List<ReportDTO> resultReportDTOS = new ArrayList<>(); //More than a million

for (int id : params.getIds()) {
        List<ReportDTO> reportDTOs = reportRepository.getDataSource(params.getProjectId(), id);
        resultReportDTOS.addAll(reportDTOs);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to increase `-Xmx<size>` for your jvm?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Increasing memory is not possible, it already rests on 32 GB

Comment: Presizing the arraylist may help a little - `new ArrayList<>(guessSize)` - but it looks like you have more serious issues with your memory usage.

Comment: Reading such a high volume of data at once produces out of memory error. I believe you need to write data in batch.

Comment: In batch mode? Could you please explain. The problem is that I need to transfer all the data at once to jasper

Comment: @ДжейкМорган instead of reading all data [millions of records] at once, you form a batch of data [it's essentially grouping data in certain size for example 100] and write and repeat the same process until the whole data you need.  How are you fetching data ? If you're using spring boot there is spring boot batch processing. Look around in documentation you'll find it.

Comment: An `ArrayList` with a million objects consumes less than 6MB or maybe 12MB if you’re using flat 64 bit pointers. In either case, not challenging at all. The problem is not the list, but the million `ReportDTO` objects resp. their associated resources.